# Is there more elements beside resistor, capacitor etc

Tags: capacitor

If relation C = (dQ/dV) defines a capacitor as element,
what woudl raleations like (d2Q/d2V) and so on would represent? New elements or not? How is this related with current and voltage harmonious components?
How does it relates to Taylor series?

Comment: A capacitor only behaves like a first order system, there is no second order effects to model.

Answer (score 4):

There are four fundamental circuit elements based on the relations of electrical characteristics:

1. Resistor
2. Capacitor
3. Inductor
4. [Memristor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memristor)

[image]

Comment: Leon Chua's "Memristor - The Missing Circuit Element," IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON CIRCUIT THEORY, VOL. CT-18, NO. 5, SEPTEMBER 1971, is worth reading, too. He discusses the 6 ways of connecting pairs of the four fundamental circuit variables you show: \$q\$, \$i\$, \$v\$, and \$\varphi\$. But time constructs two of the four from the other two. So there really are just two fundamentals, and time, as \$\textrm{d}q=i\:\textrm{d}t\$ and \$\textrm{d}\varphi=v\:\textrm{d}t\$. Moving from the top pair in the diagram through the slanted lines to the bottom pair introduces time.

Comment: As the angled lines indicate, yes. And since you can relate voltage and charge by energy, you could simplify that further to charge, energy, and time.

Comment: Yes, I actually prefer that, too. I guess my point was to _highlight_ that there are two fundamentals which are time-independent, \$v\$ and \$q\$, and two which are then developed by the arbitrary introduction of time into the system, \$i\$ and \$\varphi\$. To me, partly more interesting still because of the covariant formulation of Maxwell's using the special theory of relativity. Time is very interesting in its own right. But I'm off-topic by now, I'm sure.